# Save jQuery to Database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

Currently I'm running a site that grabs some third-party API data that grabs a currency price saves it as "msg.data.closing_price.value" and then allows me to compare it against other products in a local price by creating strings like this:

```
$('#dollar-price').html('&ETH;' +Math.round10 (1/msg.data.closing_price.value, -2));
```

I'm looking for a way to be able to take the output of the jQuery above add a timestamp and throw it into a database so that I can later add some historical data, yet I haven't been to successful in finding a method, at least one that I understood

As a really new dev who struggled even getting jQuery going in the first place I'm at a total loss and could use a shove in the right direction!

Comment: you could use ajax to update data to database. If you use google, you'll find many tutorials regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in jQuery - not simply at least. What you can do is take the value and send it to some PHP-side script that may do what you want:

```
$.post( "/path/to/script", { price: msg.data.closing_price.value } );
```

and in the script - after some suitable input checks -

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
if (is_numeric($price)) {
    // some range checks maybe

    // Insert into database proper. PDO recommended.
    insertRows($table, array(
        'price' => (float)$price;
    ));
}
```

The timestamp may be automatically added by the database using the appropriate data type and default (`DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`), or you can get it yourself with `time()` or any suitable function. Beware the timezone, and never trust the data sent by the client.

What you **really** ought to do, though, is to check out the third-party API and see how it is called and what does it return. You may use Firebug or Chrome WebDev to do this. Suppose it's a simple POST call to `/othersite/pricelist/productCode`, then all you need to do is to reimplement the call using cURL (or maybe even `file_get_contents($url);` if it is a GET call), on the server; the client need not enter into this. Using **cron jobs** you may then also save the data regularly without user intervention, plot them using [`RRD`](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph.en.html) from [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.rrd.php), and so on and so forth.